# Return multiple parameters in Python

Tags: python, function, ffmpeg

I am trying to re-write one of my scripts using functions. It is analyzing couple of transport stream files in a directory and then returns the GoP size of all TS files using ffprobe and writes the json file to the log directory. So this is originally my script and it works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import json
import os.path

recdir = "/home/user/recordings/"
logdir = "/home/user/logs/"


for input_file in os.listdir(recdir):
        gop_list = []
        p = 0
        fname = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0]
        if input_file.endswith(".ts"):
                abs_file = recdir + "/" + input_file
                # Execute the ffprobe command for analysing the GoP Structure
                gop_data = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-read_intervals', "%+10", '-print_format', 'json', '-select_streams', 'v', '-show_frames', '-show_entries', 'frame=coded_picture_number,key_frame,pict_type', abs_file])
#               print gop_data
                # Write output to a file
                out = open("{}_gop_data.json".format(fname), "w+")
                out.write(gop_data)
                out.close
                #End of writing
                # Loading the json file
                gop = json.loads(gop_data.decode('utf-8'))
                print "-------------------------- GoP information for {} ------------------------------".format(input_file)
                print
                # Calculating the GoP length of the video(difference between two IDR frames)
                for i in range(len(gop["frames"])):
                        if (gop["frames"][i]["pict_type"]) == "I" and (gop["frames"][i]["key_frame"] == 1):
                                gop_list.append(i)
                                p += 1
                        # Printing the first 5 results if present
                for r in range(1, p):
                        print "GoP frame length Nr: {0} is: {1}".format(r, (gop_list[r] - gop_list[r-1] + 1))
                print

                for i in range(len(gop["frames"])):
                        if (gop["frames"][i]["pict_type"]) == "I" and (gop["frames"][i]["key_frame"] == 1):
                                gop_list.append(i)
                                p += 1
```

I want to create 3 functions out of it. One is to execute the ffprobe command and to save the output to a variable "gop". Another one is to write the json output to different files and the third is to present the data to the command line. The problem currently is that the first function is returning the gop parameter but it returns only the last one. Please keep in mind that these files are quite big. So I think I need to return the name of the file and the corresponding GoP file at the same time and use this data for the other two functions (write_gop_data and iframe_calculator) but I am not sure how I can do that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import json
import os.path

recdir = "/home/user/recordings/"
logdir = "/home/user/logs/"

def reading_gop_data(input_directory):
        for input_file in os.listdir(input_directory):
                fname = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0]
                if input_file.endswith(".ts"):
                        abs_file = recdir + input_file
                        # Execute the ffprobe command for analysing the GoP Structure
                        gop = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-read_intervals', "%+10", '-print_format', 'json', '-select_streams', 'v', '-show_frames', '-show_entries', 'frame=coded_picture_number,key_frame,pict_type', abs_file])
                        return gop

def write_gop_data(gop_data, input_directory, save_directory):
        for input_file in os.listdir(input_directory):
                fname = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0]
                out = open("{}{}_gop.json".format(save_directory, fname), "w+")
                out.write(gop_data)
                out.close

def iframe_calculator(gop_data, input_directory):
        for input_file in os.listdir(input_directory):
                gop_list = []
                p = 0
                if input_file.endswith(".ts"):
                        gop_json = json.loads(gop_data.decode('utf-8'))
                        print "-------------------------- GoP information for {} ------------------------------".format(input_file)
                        print
                        # Calculating the GoP length of the video(difference between two IDR frames)
                        for i in range(len(gop_json["frames"])):
                                if (gop_json["frames"][i]["pict_type"]) == "I" and (gop_json["frames"][i]["key_frame"] == 1):
                                        gop_list.append(i)
                                        p += 1
                        # Printing the first 5 results if present
                for r in range(1, p):
                        print "GoP frame length Nr: {0} is: {1}".format(r, (gop_list[r] - gop_list[r-1] + 1))
                print


# reading_gop_data(recdir)
write_gop_data(reading_gop_data(recdir), recdir, logdir)
iframe_calculator(reading_gop_data(recdir), recdir)
```

Comment: fix your indent.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving your aim without too much boilerplate would be to use a combination of the [yield](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/) keyword and a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)

For example you could change the last line in your your first function from:

```
return gop
```

to:

```
yield (gop, abs_file)
```

This will allow you to return multiple values at a time from your function and will also "generate" a value every time this line is executed. What the 'yield' keyword does is turn your function into a generator.

Also, now that you're returning the file name, you now longer need to iterate through the input directory in your other two functions so you can remove the line below in the `write_gop_data` and `iframe_calculator` functions:

```
for input_file in os.listdir(input_directory):
```

Then when you're iterating through your recordings data you can do so with the following structure:

```
for gop_data in reading_gop_data(recdir):
    gop, file_name = gop_data
    print "Processing file: " + file_name
    write_gop_data(gop, file_name, logdir)
    iframe_calculator(gop, file_name)
```

On each iteration, the `gop_data` variable is populated by the `reading_gop_data` function and then you can unpack your tuple into the two variables you need to perform the rest of your processing.

Comment: this code doesn't work, It just shows me Processing file .... and then shows me the iframe information for all the files there with the first GoP value calculated wrong, then Processing another file and again all the information for the files with the first GoP value calculated wrong

Comment: Processing file: /home/user/recordings/1.ts
 GoP information for 1.ts 
GoP frame length Nr: 0 is: -494
GoP frame length Nr: 1 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 2 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 3 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 4 is: 100

GoP information for 2.ts 
GoP frame length Nr: 0 is: -494
GoP frame length Nr: 1 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 2 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 3 is: 100
GoP frame length Nr: 4 is: 100

and so on

Comment: You may need to pull a running `p` variable out of the `iframe_calculator`

Comment: yes, you are right, I think I am on the right way. I just need to change a bit more my functions and it would work. Thanks for the help @sileknarf

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use generator function.

```
def reading_gop_data(input_directory):
    for input_file in os.listdir(input_directory):
        fname = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0]
        if input_file.endswith(".ts"):
            abs_file = recdir + input_file
            # Execute the ffprobe command for analysing the GoP Structure
            gop = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-read_intervals', "%+10", '-print_format', 'json', '-select_streams', 'v', '-show_frames', '-show_entries', 'frame=coded_picture_number,key_frame,pict_type', abs_file])
            yield gop
```

then you can consume this with.

```
for gop in reading_gop_data(input_directory):
    write_gop_data(gop)
```

Comment: I tried that but again the created json files are exactly the same size for all the TS files.

Answer (score 0):

So in the first function I need to use yield function as suggested by @sileknarf and @Rahul, but I need to return 3 parameters: `yield (gop, abs_file, fname)` The for loop in the following two functions should be deleted as mentioned by @sileknarf and the fname in write_gop_data has to be also deleted. Both functions should look like this:

```
def write_gop_data(gop_data, input_directory, save_directory):
        out = open("{}{}_gop.json".format(save_directory, fname), "w+")
        out.write(gop_data)
        out.close

def iframe_calculator(gop_data, input_directory):
        gop_list = []
        if input_file.endswith(".ts"):
                gop_json = json.loads(gop_data.decode('utf-8'))
                print "-------------------------- GoP information for {} ------------------------------".format(input_file)
                print
                # Calculating the GoP length of the video(difference between two IDR frames)
                for i in range(len(gop_json["frames"])):
                        if (gop_json["frames"][i]["pict_type"]) == "I" and (gop_json["frames"][i]["key_frame"] == 1):
                                gop_list.append(i)
                # Printing the first 5 results if present
        for r in range(1, 5):
                print "GoP frame length Nr: {} is: {}".format(r, (gop_list[r] - gop_list[r-1] + 1))
        print

for gop_data in reading_gop_data(recdir):
        gop, input_file, fname = gop_data
        write_gop_data(gop, recdir, logdir)
        iframe_calculator(gop, recdir)
```